# Data is not populating from list in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to angular js and I'm having an issue. My repeat code is

```
<div id="list" ng-controller="Controller">
    <ul class="list-group">
         <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in username">
             <div>
                 <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.name}}</h2>
                 <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.un}}</h3>
             </div>
          </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And my controller is :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('Controller',function Controller($login) {
    $login.username=[
    {
        "name":"Dr. Sarfaraz",
        "un":"dsar@gmail.com",
        "pass":"12345212e2"
    },
    {
        "name":"Dr. Abdullah",
        "un":"abdul@yahoo.com",
        "pass":"13e45212e2"
    },
    {
        "name":"admin",
        "un":"admin@ehr.com",
        "pass":"*2345*12e2"
    }
]; });
```

When I run this code, the data is not populated from the list. Can anybody help me to solve this problem....:)

Comment: Any error in `console`?

Comment: `$login` should be `$scope`, or `['$scope', function Controller($login){`, or use `as syntax` and `this.username=[`

Comment: @Tushar no there is no error on console

Comment: @Grundy by doing this the prolem is still there

Comment: do you want to minify the scope into login ??

Comment: @Waleed, by doing what? i provide a few solution what you try?

Comment: @Grundy i try ur both solutions but they r not working

Comment: @Waleed, see answer - code snippet work

Comment: @Waleed, seems like you forgot `ng-app` attribute

Answer (score 2):

Pass value in $scope instead of $login:

```
,function Controller($login, $scope){
$scope.username=[
```

I can think you're replacing $scope with $login. In angularjs, the variable name should be exact if you want to use $scope you don't rename it to anything else.

Answer (score 1):

few solutions:

- `$login` should be `$scope`

  ```
  myApp.controller('Controller', function Controller($scope) {
    $scope.username = [{
      "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
      "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
      "pass": "12345212e2"
    }, {
      "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
      "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
      "pass": "13e45212e2"
    }, {
      "name": "admin",
      "un": "admin@ehr.com",
      "pass": "*2345*12e2"
    }];
  });
  ```
- `['$scope', function Controller($login){`,

  ```
  myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope',
    function Controller($login) {
      $login.username = [{
        "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
        "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
        "pass": "12345212e2"
      }, {
        "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
        "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
        "pass": "13e45212e2"
      }, {
        "name": "admin",
        "un": "admin@ehr.com",
        "pass": "*2345*12e2"
      }];
    }
  ]);
  ```
- use as syntax and `this.username=[`

  ```
  myApp.controller('Controller', function Controller() {
    this.username = [{
      "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
      "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
      "pass": "12345212e2"
    }, {
      "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
      "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
      "pass": "13e45212e2"
    }, {
      "name": "admin",
      "un": "admin@ehr.com",
      "pass": "*2345*12e2"
    }];
  });
  ```

  and in html `ng-controller="Controller as ctrl"` and `ng-repeat="item in ctrl.username"`

as you can see in next snippet - all solutions works, and if you not see any errors in console, so probably you forget add `ng-app` attribute.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Controller', function Controller($scope) {
  $scope.username = [{
    "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
    "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
    "pass": "12345212e2"
  }, {
    "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
    "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
    "pass": "13e45212e2"
  }, {
    "name": "admin",
    "un": "admin@ehr.com",
    "pass": "*2345*12e2"
  }];
});

myApp.controller('Controller2', ['$scope',
  function Controller($login) {
    $login.username = [{
      "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
      "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
      "pass": "12345212e2"
    }, {
      "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
      "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
      "pass": "13e45212e2"
    }, {
      "name": "admin",
      "un": "admin@ehr.com",
      "pass": "*2345*12e2"
    }];
  }
]);

myApp.controller('Controller3', function Controller() {
  this.username = [{
    "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
    "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
    "pass": "12345212e2"
  }, {
    "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
    "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
    "pass": "13e45212e2"
  }, {
    "name": "admin",
    "un": "admin@ehr.com",
    "pass": "*2345*12e2"
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div id="list" ng-controller="Controller">
    First:
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in username">
        <div>
          <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.name}}</h2>
          <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.un}}</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="list" ng-controller="Controller2">
    Second:
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in username">
        <div>
          <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.name}}</h2>
          <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.un}}</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="list" ng-controller="Controller3 as ctrl">
    third:
    <ul class="list-group">
      <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.username">
        <div>
          <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.name}}</h2>
          <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.un}}</h3>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.username=[{//data}]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me. Don't forget to set the `ng-app` in the div attributes and inject `'$scope'` before to use as argument of your controller.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" id="list" ng-controller="Controller">
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="item in username">
            <div>
                <h2 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.name}}</h2>
                <h3 class="list-group-item-heading">{{item.un}}</h3>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('Controller', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.username = [{
        "name": "Dr. Sarfaraz",
        "un": "dsar@gmail.com",
        "pass": "12345212e2"
    }, {
        "name": "Dr. Abdullah",
        "un": "abdul@yahoo.com",
        "pass": "13e45212e2"
    }, {
        "name": "admin",
        "un": "admin@ehr.com",
        "pass": "*2345*12e2"
    }];
}]);

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I launch this code on a web-browser, it's working so If you can copy the log error, I will see what's the problem.

Comment: there is no  error the output is 

    {{item.name}}
    {{item.un}}

this on browser

Comment: Look what I'm getting : https://jsfiddle.net/9rmfk1mj/. And you should look in the console of your browser, maybe be there is some errors logged into it.